# How do I pass parameters into a jQuery.click() function on a <span> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have used the jQuery.click() function in the past with buttons and have had nothing but success, but I tried to use it to click on a `<span>` and it doesn't work.

Also I noticed that it automatically executed my function without listening to the click.

Judging how I used it on buttons, this would be the syntax:

```
<p><span id="example">Click Here</span></p>

   $("#example").click(exampleFunction(p1, p2));
```

But it does not seem to work. Again it just executes it without the click even taking place. I even tried:

```
$(document).on("click", "#example", exampleFunction(p1, p2));
```

Still no luck, same results.

I am making a weather app and my goal with this is to toggle the temperature between Fahrenheit and Celsius by clicking on the unit. I made a copy of the code for the app on codepen.io here:

[Codepen Weather App](http://codepen.io/estermer/pen/wWvJrV?editors=1010)

I appreciate the help!

Comment: you are executing the function, not passing a reference to it: `$(document).on("click", "#unit", toggleTemp);` if you want to pass the two parameters you will need to wrap it in anonymous function

Comment: I think you hit the nail on the head. because I have tried what everyone else said.. I have 2 parameters I have to pass to my function.

Comment: i  changed the way the question was phrased because i think that was the actual problem instead of using the function on the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you should try something like this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#example", function() {
  console.log('Hello World');
});
```

Using the `function()` definition alone give me `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (`.

What you're doing is binding an anonymous function to the click. If you were doing this somewhat differently, like `MyFunction()`, then it would only execute the function.

If you had `MyFunction` you could still trigger it using click like so:

```
function MyFunction() {
  console.log('Hurra!')
}

$('#example').click(MyFunction)
```

Notice that I didn't use the parentheses otherwise it will actually run the function instead of binding it.

Comment: What if I have to pass parameters into it?

Comment: They will be implicit! You'll only need to make sure `MyFunction` definition looks like `function MyFunction(event) {`.

Comment: Though, I personally think, if you're passing non-event parameters, you shouldn't view the function doing the action and the event function as the same. More like `click(function() { MyFunction(param1, param2) })`.

Comment: Ok awesome that is what I wanted to know! I will give that a try and see if that works!

Comment: No problem, glad to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```js
$('#example').click(bleepme);

function bleepme(){
   alert('hi');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p><span id="example">Click Here</span></p>
```

Note that the on-click call to the bleepme function does not have parens -- if you put parens there, it will run the function at document.ready, but not upon click.

[Example - no parens on click](https://jsfiddle.net/j7fn7874/)

[Example 2 - parens on click](https://jsfiddle.net/j7fn7874/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Well you should supply a body to the function :)

```
$("#example").click(function() {
    alert('clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you really want to pass parameters into into the function.  By the time someone is clicking on the temperature to toggle the units, the document.ready function has finished executing. You actually want to read the values for temp and units from the DOM or from local storage. So, you don't need to pass parameters into your function, which should make things a bit easier.

Answer (score -1):

I think you code need to work like this way

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#example').on('click',function(){
    // Some of your logic here
  });
});
```

Comment: nope, he has an `id` on the span and your example actions on a `class`